# Deleting from a tableview with multiple sections

Tags: swift, tableview, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row in a `UITableView` that contains multiple sections. All the tutorials I have see deletes a row when there is 1 section.

My data [[String]]:

```
[["Section 0, Item 0", "Section 0, Item 1"], ["Section 1, Item 0"]]
```

No matter what row I swipe I get the error:

`'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'`

My code for deleting:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let pulled = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Pulled", handler: {(_, _, completionHandler) in
        self.pullList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        
        completionHandler(true)
    })
    
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [pulled])
}
```

If there is a tutorial specifically for this that would be awesome. My sections could have anywhere from 1-4 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pullList` is `[[String]]` you have to delete

```
self.pullList[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: WOW. That worked. I had a feeling I was overthinking this and the answer was going to be something so simple.